# Action Script 3 - skipped action on timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, timeline

I have a problem with my code. I want to make a home page and another 3 pages ( 1,2,3 ). When I click from home page to page 1, the prev-next arrows are working but if I want to jump from home page to page 2 or 3, the arrows stoped working ( it looks like the action from frame 2 is jumped and unreadable ). What can I do to make them work even if I want to jump from home page to page 2 or 3?

Here is the source scene:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3826668/HomePage.fla
and here is timeline screenshot:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3826668/AS3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I can't open your file directly, but from skimming the data inside and screenshot, it looks like you need to move all your button initialling code (setting the click handlers, etc) to the first frame (where it's sure to be executed) And make the buttons exist on that frame too (since you need access to them). To prevent the buttons from being visible on those frames, you could just hide them initially in code by setting the visible property to false on them.

There is another way that involves putting code inside your buttons (assuming they are just regular movieclips), but I don't recommend it as usually it is better to have your code in 1 spot rather then scattered in multiple clips (which can also lead to unpredictable behaviour).